# drop nearly duplicates (pandas)

Tags: pandas, drop-duplicates

I have a dataframe with three columns:

'id', 'subject', 'delta',

I would like a function that considers lines where id and subject are repeated as duplicates, but delta, which is an integer, can be considered as duplicates if the difference between two lines of delta (with the same id and subject) is smaller or equal to 10

example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'id':[1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5], 'subject':['a','b','b','c','d','e','e','f','g'],'delta': [100, 110,112,200,120,220,223,400,112]})
```

I would like as output:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'id':[1,2,2,3,4,4,5], 'subject':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],'delta': [100,112,200,120,223,400,112]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the values per group, then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with the [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) not ≤ 10:

```
df2 = (
  df1.sort_values(by=['id', 'subject'])
    .loc[lambda d: ~d.groupby(['id', 'subject'])['delta'].diff().le(10)]
)
```

Or:

```
df2 = df1.loc[lambda d: ~d.sort_values(by=['id', 'subject'])
                          .groupby(['id', 'subject'])['delta'].diff(-1).le(10)]
```

Output:

```
   id subject  delta
0   1       a    100
1   2       b    110
3   2       c    200
4   3       d    120
5   4       e    220
7   4       f    400
8   5       g    112
```